# Javascript add margins between each object in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript  and I'm building a connect four game to learn about javascript. The problem is that I am unable to add margins between the 'o' so they all look clumped together.
I would like help adding margins or padding between the 'o's. Some thoughts are that I may need to add each row of 'o' in a table. However, I'm updating it through the javascript function. How do I get around that?

My javascript file

```
var first_row  = ['o','o','o','o','o','o','o'];

onload = function ()
     {
       document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = first_row;
     }
```

HTML file

```
<h1 class="space" id="row1"></h1>
```

Comment: Wrap them in a span.  Or use `letter-spacing` (in css): `#row1 { letter-spacing: 5px; } `

Comment: This isn't really a JS question; it's more of a CSS question.  Just for fun, though, you could do `innerHTML = first_row.join('&nbsp;&nbsp;');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to encapsulate them into  tags and put css rules on them.

A simple solution would be:

```
var first_row  = ['<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>','<span>o</span>'];

onload = function ()
 {
   document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = first_row;
 }
```

And in a css file:

```
span {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you need a `join` in there, don't you?

Comment: Sweet that worked! @Andy I didn't need to join anything there.

Comment: @jmoon90, so you wanted the commas separating the zeros?

Comment: @Andy not necessarily. If I took all the commas and quotes out I can get 1 big lump of '<span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span>' but this breaks it because I can't target a specific 'o'

Comment: The example is too simple to provide more than a hint as to how css works. But @Andy, if you look at his code, he did the exact same thing as me, without the "<span>" so all I did was encapsulate his characters in said spans. With hindsight, were I to read this later, I would indeed be baffled at the lack of join o_O. Wonder why that works !

Answer (score 2):

In pure javascript (not using jquery) with a for in loop than append spans with the '0's for styling.

```
var first_row  = ['o','o','o','o','o','o','o'];
var row = document.getElementById('row1');

for (var i in first_row) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = first_row[i];
  row.appendChild(span);  
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/95JqK/17/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use CSS on the class="space" elements

```
.space{
    padding: 8px;
}
```